# Which path for the Modelsim environment variable

Tags: modelsim

in order to run and use all modelsim commands like vcom, vsim etc. which enivronment variables are set in a windows system when NOT using the GUI to run those commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the binary path into `PATH` or call all commands with absolute paths.